# ubuntu server participating in ddos attacks

Tags: process, postfix

We have an ubuntu-11.04 server running postfix which seems to be participating in an attack on other computers.  The following processes were observed on the server:

```
www-data  6465 28192  0 08:52 ?        00:00:00 /bin/bash ./su 62.150
www-data  6469  6465  0 08:52 ?        00:00:00 sleep 10
www-data 19614     1 63 Nov14 ?        08:48:26 klogd -x
www-data 28191     1  0 Nov13 ?        00:00:00 sh -c ./rand 2>&1 3>&1
www-data 28192 28191  0 Nov13 ?        00:00:17 /bin/bash ./rand
www-data 31401     1  0 Nov12 ?        00:00:00 sh -c ./rand 2>&1 3>&1
www-data 31402 31401 20 Nov12 ?        14:45:44 /bin/bash ./rand
```

Also, the following entries were in the `/var/log/auth.log`

```
Nov 10 13:46:06 smtp2 su[21335]: pam_unix(su:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=33 euid=0 tty=/dev/pts/0 ruser=www-data rhost=  user=root
Nov 10 13:46:07 smtp2 su[21335]: pam_authenticate: Authentication failure
Nov 10 13:46:07 smtp2 su[21335]: FAILED su for root by www-data
Nov 10 13:46:07 smtp2 su[21335]: - /dev/pts/0 www-data:root
Nov 10 13:46:08 smtp2 su[21336]: pam_unix(su:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=33 euid=0 tty=/dev/pts/0 ruser=www-data rhost=  user=root
Nov 10 13:46:10 smtp2 su[21336]: pam_authenticate: Authentication failure
Nov 10 13:46:10 smtp2 su[21336]: FAILED su for root by www-data
Nov 10 13:46:10 smtp2 su[21336]: - /dev/pts/0 www-data:root
Nov 10 13:46:10 smtp2 su[21337]: pam_unix(su:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=33 euid=0 tty=/dev/pts/0 ruser=www-data rhost=  user=root
Nov 10 13:46:13 smtp2 su[21337]: pam_authenticate: Authentication failure
Nov 10 13:46:13 smtp2 su[21337]: FAILED su for root by www-data
Nov 10 13:46:13 smtp2 su[21337]: - /dev/pts/0 www-data:root
Nov 10 13:46:13 smtp2 su[21338]: pam_unix(su:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=33 euid=0 tty=/dev/pts/0 ruser=www-data rhost=  user=root
Nov 10 13:46:14 smtp2 su[21338]: pam_authenticate: Authentication failure
Nov 10 13:46:14 smtp2 su[21338]: FAILED su for root by www-data
```

Doing a find on the system for files named rand reveals the following:

```
find . -name rand -print
./tmp/rup/rand
```

`/tmp` has the following:

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 www-data www-data    4096 2013-11-15 10:24 rup
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data 1080938 2013-11-13 13:51 rup.tgz
```

Is this normal? It seems the server has been infected at some point even though the only open ports are pop3 and smtp. Can the server get infected using these ports?
If yes, what can be done to secure the server from further infections?

Comment: can you add the output of `w` ? Are you also running an Apache web server on the same box?

Comment: Seems a bit like something/someone managed to compromise your `www-data` user account and try to do a privilege escalation. `cat /etc/passwd | grep www-data` if the result is starting with anything else than `www-data:x:` Have you checked /var/www/* for strange files?

Comment: No doubt, your server seems compromised. You can also feel free to add the output of `lastlog`.

Comment: The output of w does not show much activity at this time.   w
 12:32:48 up 6 days, 21:26,  1 user,  load average: 3.38, 3.21, 3.10

Comment: There do not seem to be any strange files in /var/www. We did not intentionally set up an apache web server but it may have been part of the install. Passwd file shows this entry: 
www-data:x:33:33:www-data:/var/www:/bin/sh
    I was wrong about which ports are open. The following are open for tcp: www, pop3, domain, imap4, 587, https, smtp.
domain is open for udp.  Which ports should be open for just sending and receiving emails?

Comment: lastlog shows never logged in for all except the one user we do use to log in to the server

Comment: Can you tell a bit more about your email stack? E.g: postfix, dovecot? eg.? can you add `sudo lsof -i -a` to the question?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible to get infected from any service that have vulnerabilities regardless of what port or what service it is.

In your case did Ubuntu 11.04 hit end of life (EOL) October 28, 2012. Unless you are having good routines for upgrading or, detecting and patching vulnerabilities would I strongly recommend to stick with Ubuntu LTS releases for servers in production environment. Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS (long term support) would be a reasonable pick as it will be supported with security updates to April 2017.

It exist a lot of guides on How to secure Ubuntu servers, search the internet and try to filter what would be the best for your services.

If you decide to stick with Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, would i suggest to have a look at the [server guide.](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/) It also has a [security part.](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/security.html) [Fail2ban](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fail2ban) might be of your interest. But maybe most important get the [automated security upgrades](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/automatic-updates.html) rolling.